# Передача параметра в computed, VueJS

Tags: vue.js

Необходимо передать в computed поле параметр - элемент из цикла те продукт. Результат вычисления поля записывать в v-if.

Если делать без computed, то v-if работает нормально. Происходит переключение кнопок, ошибок нет.

1. без computed:

   ```
      <ul id="products">
               <li v-for="product in products">
                   <button v-if="inCart.indexOf(product.id) === -1"
                           v-on:click="addToCart(product.id)">Добавить в корзину</button>
                   <button v-else
                           v-on:click="removeFromCart(product.id)">Удалить из корзины</button>
               </li>
       </ul>
   ```

Но в общем случае удобнее использовать вычисляемое свойство.

Ошибка: "TypeError: _vm.status is not a function"

Использовать метод - не вариант, пересчет происходит для всех продуктов.

2. с computed status:

   ```
   <ul id="products">
       <li v-for="product in products">
           <button v-if="status(product.id)"
                   v-on:click="addToCart(product.id)">Добавить в корзину</button>
           <button v-else
                   v-on:click="removeFromCart(product.id)">Удалить из корзины</button>
       </li>
   </ul>
   computed: {
       status(id){
           console.log(id);
           return this.inCart.indexOf(id) === -1
       },
       products(){...},
       inCart(){...}
   }
   ```

Comment: перенесите `status` в методы

Comment: Если я перенесу status в методы, то кликнув по одной кнопке  status сработает не единожды, а столько, сколько продуктов.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал это так

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    products: [{
        id: 0,
        in_cart: false,
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        in_cart: true,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        in_cart: false,
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    addToCart(id) {
      console.log('addToCart');
      this.products[id].in_cart = true

    },
    removeFromCart(id) {
      console.log('removeFromCart')
      this.products[id].in_cart = false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul id="products">
    <li v-for="(product, index) in products" :key="product.id">
      <button v-if="!product.in_cart" @click="addToCart(index)">Добавить в корзину</button>
      <button v-else @click="removeFromCart(index)">Удалить из корзины</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Потому что, если, сделать как Вы хотите, то проблема не будет решена

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
inCart: [],
products: [
  {
    id: 0,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
  }
]
  },
  computed: {
status(){
    return (id) => {
      console.log(123)
      return this.inCart.indexOf(id) === -1
    }
},
  },
  methods: {
addToCart(id) {
  this.inCart.push(id)

},
removeFromCart(id){
  const index = this.inCart.indexOf(id);
  this.inCart.splice(index, 1)
}
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
    <div id="app">
  <ul id="products">
    <li v-for="product in products">
        <button v-if="status(product.id)"
                v-on:click="addToCart(product.id)">Добавить в корзину</button>
        <button v-else
                v-on:click="removeFromCart(product.id)">Удалить из корзины</button>
    </li>
</ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Дело в том, что продукты и соответственно их id и тд. приходят из vuex.  Те product и inCart это геттеры.

Comment: и в чем проблема с геттерами?